# Domain events with composite pattern

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design, distributed-system, bulkupdate, eda

I am trying to model a real-time collaboration application with DDD. A particular feature with some Hotspot events is CAD visualization.

## Problem #1

Multiple participants join a 3D virtual environment and one of them is designated as a facilitator. Although all participants can change various preferences for themselves, the facilitator can change preferences for all users. The users can change them back on an individual level.

The problem I am facing is, **single** vs **bulk operation**. Do I submit a granular event for bulk operations or a single event? If an existing process listens to the granular event, it will miss the bulk event unless communicated explicitly which doesn't result in so clean boundary.

## Problem #2

Interestingly enough this is a variation of problem #1 but a bit more severe. A CAD model comes with some meta-structure which is a DAG. Each leaf level structure is a group of triangles that are manipulated together. These groups of triangles are called Volume. A group of volumes forms another concept known as a Branch. A branch can contain other branches as a child. The branch+volume structure always forms a tree. Some disjoint tree branches form another concept called Group.

Now a participant can make a branch/group/volume visible and hidden. Do I publish *a single* branch-level event or create an event for *every branch/volume in the forward path?

I have thought about publishing bulk events for bulk operations and single events for single operations under the same topic. This doesn't feel good as I may introduce new bulk events and require another downstream context to break.

Alternatively, I thought about publishing both bulk and granular event with correlation_id. If a bulk event were understood, the downstream can ignore the following events with the same correlation id. Although this seems promising, Still doesn't feel good as the downstream may process events concurrently and later events could be processed earlier than the bulk event.

Can bulk operations be properly modeled using DDD? Is there a way to rethink the composite pattern which is more DDD friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) bulk event, the id can be a query for all the matching ids at that moment or the explicit matching id list. you need it, because if you want to revert the event somehow, then you will have a problem if you lose the connection between individual events. it is an infot which must be stored too.

2.) looks like some sort of weird graph, it reminds me of the knowledge graph of sciences: math, physics, chemistry, biology, etc. where everything builds on math and they are interrelated, still people want to force them into a hierarchy. the problem that there are terms which are half way between two sciences so when you select the term of one science you cannot decide which they belong to. the same solution, selecting things with queries works for this too. I thought a lot about this problem too. having a shitload individual events will require a massive storage space after a certain size. better to use bulk with queries and compute them or save the id list as a query cache, but don't duplicate anything else. as of the semi-hierarchical structure, I have no idea how to model it properly. I would use a simple graph and tag everything and query based on the tags, but still there is a sort of hierarchy, which is hard to grasp from a pure graph perspective without any kind of weighting.